# Fix for SQL UPDATE: updating all the rows to the same value instead of basing value on another table column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query to combine the columns into a comma-separated list (using this because `STRING_AGG` does not work for me probably due to an older version of SQL Server which I do not have control over):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + t1.HAZARD_code_desc 
           FROM HAZARD_codes t1 
           WHERE mask & 67584 <> 0 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '')
FROM 
    HAZARD_codes t0, sheldus51_copy sc 
WHERE 
    t0.mask & 67584 <> 0
```

This is then used to update the value of column in another table using the following query:

```
UPDATE sheldus51_copy
SET hazard_type_combo = (SELECT TOP 1 
                             STUFF((SELECT ',' + t1.HAZARD_code_desc 
                                    FROM HAZARD_codes t1 
                                    WHERE mask & sc.mask <> 0 
                                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '')
                         FROM HAZARD_codes t0, sheldus51_copy sc 
                         WHERE t0.mask & sc.mask <> 0)
```

However, the value of all the rows in the column `hazard_type_combo` are getting updated to the same value instead of being governed by the `sc.mask` value. i.e.

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = (result of an expression)
```

this updates all rows to the same value. What am I missing here?

Some data below:

Query:

```
select distinct(mask) 
from sheldus51_copy
```

Data:

```
196608
131072
32
65536
131104
2048
64
256
1
4
1024
128
16
32768
67584
2
4096
512
8
```

Query:

```
select HAZARD_code_desc, mask 
from hazard_codes
```

Result:

```
Avalanche   1
Coastal 2
Drought 4
Earthquake  8
Flooding    16
Fog 32
Hail    64
Heat    128
Hurricane/Tropical Storm    256
Landslide   512
Lightning   1024
Severe Storm/Thunder Storm  2048
Tornado 4096
Tsunami/Seiche  8192
Volcano 16384
Wildfire    32768
Wind    65536
Winter Weather  131072
```

Example query

```
select HAZARD_code_desc, mask  
from hazard_codes 
where mask & 67584 <> 0
```

will match the rows where mask is 2048 and 65536 and therefore should set the value for `hazard_type_combo` to `Severe Storm/Thunder Storm, Wind`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: not sure how to join without a foreign key present

Comment: If you *really* want to combine each row from the first table with each row from the second table - use `CROSS JOIN` ....

Comment: You're absolutely and totally wrong: `CROSS JOIN` needs **nothing at all** - it will just combine each and every row from table 1, with each and every row in table 2 - there is **no need** for any common columns at all - `CROSS JOIN` does **not** have a `JOIN` condition at all ... see here for instance: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cross-join/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference and alias the sheldus51_copy table in a FROM clause at the top level, so that both the UPDATE and the nested select (correlated subquery) can reference the same rows.  Try:

```
UPDATE sc
SET hazard_type_combo = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + h.HAZARD_code_desc 
            FROM HAZARD_codes h 
            WHERE h.mask & sc.mask <> 0
            -- ORDER BY ...
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, LEN(','), '')
FROM sheldus51_copy sc
```

Suggest also adding an ORDER BY h.HAZARD_code_desc or ORDER BY h.mask if you want a predictable result.

And if sc.mask can ever be zero (no codes), you can add an ISNULL() around the expression to assign a default such as 'None' or the empty string.

Comment: Thank you so much for the previous help!